# Display without line breaks in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

> I have datagrid that it's bound to datatable, the problem is that it shows each row with multiline form like:

[image]

> XAML looks like:

```
<DataGrid    
     DataContext="{Binding DashBoardUCVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
     Foreground="Black"
     FontSize="16"                
     Background="White"
     IsReadOnly="True"
     SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexDDG}"
     SelectedValue="{Binding SelectionValueDDG}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding JobsViewDG}">        
</DataGrid>
```

> I have tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735029/10705051) answer, and added `RowHeight="50"`, but the I get:

[image]

> i.e it shows only the top part of the content. I need something like:

[image]

Comment: what does `Log` contain, i.e. does that string contain newlines?

Comment: @Default Yes...

Comment: @BugsFixer: Then you need to either remove the newlines from the `DataTable` or use a converter that removes the newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to get rid of wrapping which can be achieved using:

```
<DataGrid ...>
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
...
```

as found here [WPF DataGrid Cell Text Wrapping - set to NoWrap (False)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197947/wpf-datagrid-cell-text-wrapping-set-to-nowrap-false)

You can specify width you are willing to start with and rest will be hidden on the right side of the column.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite completly understand what you want to acomplish here. But i think there is a problem with showing multiple lines in the datagrid.

As i see it, the problem is not the datagrid is the data you send. Try to process the data before passing it to the datagrid. What i normally do when the raw data does not fit me is use a DataTable. In the datatable I can modify it's value as I need it, withdraw or adding info does is a simple matter, and then i can pas it to the DataGrid  by binding or simple passing it directly to it's ItemSource by DataTable.AsDataView().

PS: Be careful that the columns of the DataTAble and the DataGrid have to be binded between them (the datagrid column content must have the same binding name as the datatable header)